# Restore in app purchase method in my iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

These are my first steps on implementing IAP, so be easy on me. I have to implement the restore app button on my app and I don't know where to start/modify

This is my IAP class

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"

@implementation IAPHelper
@synthesize productIdentifiers = _productIdentifiers;
@synthesize products = _products;
@synthesize purchasedProducts = _purchasedProducts;
@synthesize request = _request;

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = [productIdentifiers retain];

        // Check for previously purchased products
        NSMutableSet * purchasedProducts = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
            BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
            if (productPurchased) {
                [purchasedProducts addObject:productIdentifier];
                NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            }
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
        self.purchasedProducts = purchasedProducts;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)requestProducts {

    self.request = [[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers] autorelease];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    _request.delegate = self;
    [_request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Received products results..."); 
    NSLog(@"Invalid ...%d", [response.invalidProductIdentifiers count]); 

    if([response.invalidProductIdentifiers count]>0)
    {
        return;
    }

    self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;

    SKProduct * proUpgradeProduct = [self.products count] == 1 ? [[self.products objectAtIndex:0] retain] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:_products];    
}

- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {    
    // TODO: Record the transaction on the server side...    
}

- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    NSLog(@"Toggling flag for: %@", productIdentifier);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [_purchasedProducts addObject:productIdentifier];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier];

}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}


- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
    if (wasSuccessful)
    {
        // send out a notification that we’ve finished the transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
    else
    {
        // send out a notification for the failed transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        // error!
        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)buyProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", productIdentifier);

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_productIdentifiers release];
    _productIdentifiers = nil;
    [_products release];
    _products = nil;
    [_purchasedProducts release];
    _purchasedProducts = nil;
    [_request release];
    _request = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I have been reading some things, but in the part of 'updatedTransactions' I have some issues on adding the SKPaymentRestore.

Could someone give me some advice?
thanks for reading/helping!

Comment: There's also a Cocoapod named IAPManager which does all this for you...

Comment: As this are my first steps on iap, i should first learn good how to implement all, and then add things like this. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

Use RMStore for In app purchase.A lightweight iOS library for In-App Purchases.RMStore adds blocks and notifications to StoreKit, plus receipt verification, content downloads and transaction persistence. All in one class without external dependencies.
Add this in Restore Button. 
     Restore transactions

```
     [[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^{
    NSLog(@"Transactions restored");
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
     }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code on your restore button click

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Comment: Sure?! I was searching and found out that i should add new methods like  :  
`-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue'
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error`

Comment: Yes Sure ,just add the two lines.

Comment: On the `- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction`
?

Comment: write down the new method restoreButtonClicked and put these lines in that.

Comment: and where should I call that method?

Comment: I put this on my IAPHelper.m class:
`- (void)storeRestoreButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}`

is that ok?

Comment: yes and call this function in same way as you calling buyProductIdentifier method from your view controller.

Comment: Im having some issues on calling this... it doesn't appear to sellect. This is the button:
`-(IBAction)payWithInAppPurchase:(id)sender
{
    [[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper] buyProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId];
}`

by the way, i have more classes that work with the IAPHelper, like InAppRageHelper and Reachability.

Comment: It doesn't seems to call the StoreRestoreButtonTapped method on my Menu class where I implemented the action of IAP (this action):
`(IBAction)payWithInAppPurchase:(id)sender { [[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper] buyProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId]; }`

should I put there the call of the store?